# How to iterate through an array in an NgIf statement - Angular / Ionic

Tags: ngfor, angular-ng-if

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let house of (houses | async)">
  <ion-list *ngIf="house.members[0] === currentUserId">
    <ion-item button (click)="goToHouseDetailsPage(this.house)">
      <ion-icon class="listIcon" item-left name="exit"></ion-icon>
      {{ house.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

This code is working and is displaying only the houses that the current user is a member of. I want to be able to iterate through this array, for when there are many members of one house.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to access the value of each item in `house.members`, then replace ngIf with this:
`*ngFor="let member of house.members" `

Comment: Yes I have tried :
*ngFor="let house of (houses | async)"
*ngFor="let member of house.members"
*ngIf="member == UserId"
In 3 seperate tags. Is this correct?

I am getting zero results. I have check that the UserId is set, and is the same as in the house.members array

Comment: Got it working - The HTML in the last comment worked, once i changed userId to this.userId.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Great! I'm glad it did. I will write the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value of each item in `house.members`, then replace `ngIf` with `ngFor` like this:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let house of (houses | async)">
  <ion-list *ngFor="let member of house.members">
    <ion-item button (click)="goToHouseDetailsPage(house)">
      <ion-icon class="listIcon" item-left name="exit"></ion-icon>
      {{ house.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```